# Where to apply try catch in controller's action in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, try-catch, sqlconnection

Here is my code in action in which user is inserted in database.
Kindly let me know where to apply try catch blocks to prevent any type of exception occurs in this scenario.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user.Type = 'J';
            user.DateOfJoining = DateTime.Now;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SignupUser", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",user.FirstName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",user.LastName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",user.Email);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",user.Password);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile",user.Mobile);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City",user.City);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateProvince",user.StateProvince);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country",user.Country);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type",user.Type);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfJoining",user.DateOfJoining);
                    connection.Open();
                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    return RedirectToAction("account");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the codes inside of if block should be in try catch block in order to catch exception on connection to database in the first using block.